# Are there verbs that conjugate with the person in the simple past or simple future?

Tags: verbs, conjugation

We all know that verbs conjugate according to the person in the simple present, typically with the third person singular.

My question is: Are there verbs that change according to the person in the **simple past** or **simple future** tenses? Is "to be" the ONLY such example? (Was/Were)

Thank you

Comment: Apart from was/were/am, there is no conjugation in English. The third-person singular simple present takes an s (or es, in does). That is it.

Comment: It could hardly be simpler... ;-)

Comment: I don't get that "simple future tense" bit. *I will **be** ready, You will **have** fun, He will **like** that, We will **go** tomorrow, They will **do** it*. All the highlighted terms are infinitives, and the "future indicator" ***will*** is always the same regardless of the particular verb that follows.

Comment: There are perhaps some lexical examples: "*I* borrowed the car without asking, *you* went for a joyride, *he* committed grand theft auto." ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, verb BE is the only one verb that changes in the past (simple past and past continuous) according to the subject. All verbs in the simple present tense add an "s" or "es" when conjugated with the third person singular pronouns (he, she, it). As well as in the past, verb BE is the only one that changes according to the subject in the present continuous. In the future simple tense, there is no change because all subject pronouns take "will" + an action verb to form the future simple. However, the structure "be going to + verb", verb BE does change according to the subject just as in the simple present and present continuous forms. I hope this helped.
Cheers!

Comment: Except it is not conjugation. It is a morphemic change in the third person simple present singular.

Comment: @Lambie: The term you're looking for is . . . \*drum roll\* . . . conjugation!

Comment: The only thing I might add is that if modal auxiliaries such as *can, should, must* are considered verbs, they are exceptions to your statement that “All verbs in the simple present tense add an ‘s’ or ‘es’”

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely!
Verb 'to be' is the only one.